# Как записать x^n в программе?

Tags: c++

Пользуюсь библиотекой `<Math>`. Нужно задать формулу, по которой будет находиться последовательно каждый член (`-3-4x-5x^2...`).

```
for(d=-3;n=1;n++)
{
  d=d*x-x^n
}
```

Как задать x^n?

Answer (score 5):

Возведение в степень:

```
#include <cmath>

double res = pow (x, n);
```

Кстати, какая платформа и компилятор?

И еще: если возводите в целочисленную степень (особенно небольшую), то быстрее просто перемножить числа.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае пригодится функция poly(...) из math.h

Ну ладно, уважаемый [[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg), без poly():

```
double Polynom(const double x, const int n)
{
  double R = 3.0, powX = 1.0;
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
     powX *= x;
     R += (i + 3) * powX;
  }
  return -R;
}
```

Comment: Но это, кажись, нестандартная функция, в Линуксе ее, к примеру, нет.

Comment: @mikillskegg. Что такое "стандартная" функция, уважаемый коллега?

Comment: Ну, это типа функция, наличие которой в библиотеке обязательно согласно стандарту. Как-то так...